# Equivalent Spring custom Collection property editor when using JSF

Tags: java, spring, jsf, binding, collections

I would like to know how to use Converters in Java Server Faces similar to Spring collection property editor

Suppose the following model

```
public class Group {

    private String name;

    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    // getter's and setter's
}
```

And equivalent form

```
<form ...>
    <h1>Group form</h1>
    <label for="name">Enter name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name"/>

    <label for="users">Select users</label>
    <!--value attribute stores userId-->
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="users"/> User 1
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="users"/> User 2
    <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="users"/> User 3
</form>
```

If i use Spring to bind users property in Group class, i call

```
binder.registerCustomEditor(List.class, new CustomCollectionEditor() {
    protected Object convertElement(Object userId)  {
        return new User((Integer) userId);
    }
});
```

How do i get the same effect when using Java Server Faces ?

regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you can implement [`javax.faces.convert.Converter`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html). Its API is pretty self-explaining: write the `getAsString()` method accordingly that it returns the `String` representation of the `Object`, which can be under each the technical ID such as `userId`. Then, to get JSF set the right `Object` during apply request parameters phase, you need to implement `getAsObject()` that it returns the `Object` associated with the given `String` value.

Basically:

```
public class UserConverter implements Converter {

    private UserDAO userDAO = SomeDAOManager.getUserDAO();

    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return String.valueOf(((User) value).getId());
    }

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        return userDAO.find(Long.valueOf(value));
    }

}
```

Register it in `faces-config.xml` as follows:

```
<converter>
    <converter-for-class>com.example.model.User</converter-for-class>
    <converter-class>com.example.converter.UserConverter</converter-class>
</converter>
```

That should be it. For more insights you may [this](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html) or [this](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/09/objects-in-hselectonemenu.html) article useful.

Comment: Thank you, BalusC (+1). But is it mapped to users property automatically ?

Comment: You don't need to worry about that. The conversion is fully transparent. Just define once in `faces-config.xml` and you should be fine.

Comment: BalusC, i suppose this Converter is "global". But what should i do to set up a "local" Converter ?

Comment: Yes, it will convert every `#{user}` which JSF encounters during render response (for display) or apply request values (to set back as bean property). If you want to use it individually, use `<converter-id>` instead of `<converter-for-class>` and specify the same `<converter-id>` value in the `converterId` attribute of the JSF component. However, I question the value of just displaying `#{user}` in plain text (which would just do `String.valueOf(user)`). A global declaration is much easier and cleaner.

Comment: Note that this does **not** affect its properties like `#{user.id}`, `#{user.name}` and so on.

Comment: Is it a good pattern to use a Converter when using inheritance or should i use a PhaseListener ?

Comment: Depends on the use case. What kind of inheritance are you talking about? Super/subclasses of the model or the converter? If the first, the converter will only cover the subclasses. If the second, I don't forsee any problems. A PhaseListener is by the way only of value if you actually want to hook on any of the phases and this doesn't seem to be the case.