# Creating form to create bean with ArrayList as component

Tags: forms, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

I'm trying to do a CRUD for my bean in Spring MVC and i found it to be a bit overwhelming.

thing is, that one of bean element is ArrayList of another class

its looks like

```
class Bean{
...
    String componentName;
    ArrayList<InnerComponent> component;
...
}
```

With getters and setters ofc
and InnerComponent is pritty simple, its like

```
class InnerComponent{
String key;
String va;
}
```

now Question: How can i create form, that allows to input something in that array list?

```
<form:form commandName="Bean" id="Bean" action="#">
    <form:input type="text" path="componentName" /><br />
    ....??
    <form:button>Submit</form:button>
</form:form>
```

Can figure this out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use CustomPropertyEditors for such. 
1) [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?51338-PropertyEditor-with-List) is thread having same question.
2) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924933/equivalent-spring-custom-collection-property-editor-when-using-jsf) is stackoverflow link.
3) [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans-conventions) is Spring 3 reference doc link of propertyEditors chapter.

Comment: you are welcome. Dont forget to up my ans and accept it here :) happy springing :)